# Создание прототипов мобильных приложений

Tags: мобильные-приложения, android

Добрый день!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие программы-сервисы можно задействовать для того, чтобы создавать прототипы (макеты) мобильных приложений, в данном случае преимущественно для создания android-приложений. Нужно просто иметь возможность прорисовать все меню, лейауты и вообще навигацию приложения. Я этим никогда раньше не занимался, но думаю, это более правильно, чем сразу делать приложение, не продумав его структуры.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://ninjamock.com

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, буду разбираться.